# Schengen visa to travel from Germany to Switzerland

Tags: schengen-visas, france, switzerland

I'm traveling to Karlsruhe for a week with Schengen visa in the business category, and I would like to visit Switzerland & France during the weekends. Is this allowed or will I face any issues in Switzerland/France?

Comment: I assume you are indian passport holder with german visa. Switzerland/France is a part of schengen so you can travel freely. sometimes there are border checks on train or airport (i have seen passport control in basel airport) you just have to show your passport. Thats it!

Comment: @pbu Why the assumption on nationality?

Comment: @Dorothy His username sounds indian name.

Comment: @pbu not a good idea or respectful, IMO; preferable to ask nationality and other info (specific type of visa) and then offer an answer; comments can disappear, answers stay and offer value.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple : if you have a Schengen visa, you can go anywhere you want/need in Schengen area.

Comment: This is correct as long as the `valid for:` doesn't name only Germany (extremely rare but question does not clarify this)

Comment: It is also only correct as long as no immigration officers thinks that you are trying to use your Schengen visa for a different purpose from which it was issued for.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo you should make that an answer, with your usual clarifications.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That's misleading. For example, a multiple-entry business visa issued for frequent visits to a company in one place may be used for a beach vacation to another place. Perhaps a better way to say it would be "as long as no immigration officer thinks that you are using your visa fraudulently or committed fraud in your application."

Comment: @phoog You are completely right. What I said only applies to single-entry visas.

Comment: To be honest, using a business visa to enjoy a vacation over the week end after your working week isn't an issue... It is rather the opposite that could be an issue (tourist visa used to work).

Comment: @Laurent that is also true: even a single-entry visa issued for business purposes does not preclude tourism that is incidental to the business trip.  And, because Schengen doesn't actually classify visas as business or pleasure, it's also allowed for someone to plan a tourist trip and then later schedule a business meeting during that trip.  You are right that this "could be an issue," because it might appear that the original application was disingenuous, but if the traveler can show that subsequent meeting arose independently then it should be allowed.